# Python agrupar chaves com valores iguais no dicionário

Tags: python, dicionário

Olá, preciso de uma ajuda com dicionários, por favor!

Tenho o seguinte dicionário:

`dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': [4, 5, 6]}`

o que eu preciso é agrupar as chaves que possuem os mesmos valores, esperando um resultado assim:

`dict = {0:{['a', 'c'],[1, 2, 3]}, 1:{['b', 'd'],[4, 5, 6]}}`

Obrigado

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Início rápido**

Basta copiar e colar a função dentro da seção '**Código**' (que está abaixo) em seu script e leia a seção '**Como usar**' (também abaixo) para resolver seu problema, se quiser mais detalhes, leia o post inteiro e também os comentários dentro da função

**Sobre seu problema**

Construí um código exclusivamente para sua necessidade, porém fiz algumas modificações quanto a estrutura de retorno, veja:

Vc queria:

`dict = {0:{['a', 'c'],[1, 2, 3]}, 1:{['b', 'd'],[4, 5, 6]}}`

O que construí, retorna:

`dict = [(['a', 'c'],[1, 2, 3]), (['b', 'd'],[4, 5, 6])]`

Isso foi necessário pois sua estrutura possui alguns erros sintáticos quanto a definição do tipo dicionário, e perceba que o meu retorno é uma lista, ao invés de ser {0: value, 1: value}, pois me parece mais coerente a situação e é equivalente a esse dicionário que vc definiu.

**Código**

```py
def processDict(dict):
    dict_response = [] # Array que conterá a resposta no final

    """
        Para que este algoritmo funcione, o dicionário deve estar ordenado de acordo com o valor de suas chaves,
        porém, naturalmente, dicionários em python não podem ser ordenados, o que faço nas 3 linhas abaixo é criar 
        uma estrutura equivalente à um dicionario com N chaves, do tipo [(key1, value1), (key2, value2), ..., (keyN, valueN)] (uma lista de duplas), 
        que por sua vez é ordenável.
    """
    false_dict_sort = list(dict.items()) # Obtém a estrutura mencionada acima a partir do dicionário
    false_dict_sort.sort(key=lambda e: e[1]) # Ordenando a estrutura de acordo com o valor das chaves

    """
        A função abaixo é recursiva e responsável por encontrar as chaves que possuem valores iguais
        e retorná-las em uma lista, porém é necessário que o dicionário esteja ordenando
        e por isso a estrutura criada acima é necessária
        
        :param index: indice em false_dict do valor à ser comparado
        :param false_dict: estrutura equivalente ao dicionária obtida acima na variável false_dict_sort
    """

    def getDuplicateValue(index, false_dict):

            if index + 1 < len(false_dict) and false_dict[index][1] == false_dict[index + 1][1]:
                return [false_dict[index][0]] + getDuplicateValue(index + 1, false_dict)
            else:
                return [false_dict[index][0]]

    i = 0
    while i < len(false_dict_sort):
        keys_list = getDuplicateValue(i, false_dict_sort) # retorna uma lista com as chaves que possuem valores iguais
        dict_response.append((keys_list, false_dict_sort[i][1])) # adiciona uma dupla com a lista de chaves (keys_list)
                                                                 # e o valor que essas chaves possuem em dict_response
        i += len(keys_list) #Incrementa i com o tamanho de keys

    return dict_response
```

**Como usar**

Basta copiar a função em seu script python, e chamá-la da seguinte forma:

```py
seu_dicionario = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': [4, 5, 6]}
result = processDict(seu_dicionario)
```

O retorno da função é exatamente conforme sua necessidade porém está seguindo a estrutura que mencionei acima, e salvo em `result`.

> **Dica**: adicione `print("result: ", result)` para observar o resultado

**Bônus**

Essa solução funciona para qualquer tipo de valor que as chaves dos dicionários representam, não precisa ser necessariamente uma lista (como é o seu caso), porém esse tipo deve ser único para que seja possível ordená-lo, ou seja, uma vez que uma chave do dicionário possua um valor do tipo number, todos os outros devem ser number.

Tipos válidos como entrada para a função:

```py
dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'd': [4, 5, 6]}

dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

dict = {'a': "ola", 'b': "mundo", 'c': "ola", 'd': "hello"}
```

Tipos inválidos:

```py
dict = {'a': 1, 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': "ola", 'd': [4, 5, 6]}

dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': [3], 'd': "4"}

dict = {'a': "ola", 'b': "mundo", 'c': 1, 'd': "hello"}
```